# how we can send the CSV data values in the http header manager?

Tags: jmeter

I am using J meter tool, I need to send the user name along with the HTTP header data so that I can see in the access log which user is failing. I tried adding the variable in the header Manager: user name : ${variable}
The variable i am reading form config data file when I run this I don't even see the variable send in the request in the access logs.
Can any one please help!

Comment: Is the http header manager within the scope of the request itself?

Comment: I have tried adding the http header manager in the sampler and even tried removing from each sample and adding one in the loop controller. but its not working

Comment: Can you add a few screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can not have spaces in HTTP Headers.

You'll have to change your `user name` header name to something like `username` or `user-name` elsewise your request will be rejected by HTTP server (if not earlier)

See Using [JMeter's HTTP Header Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) guide for details.